Mismatch between acceptance rate and phase transition
I have written a program for performing MC simulation of LJ (Lennard-Jones) particles.
Simulation literature says that the acceptance rate should be 20–60%.
However, I see that the position where the bend of the curve (possibly a phase transition) has taken place is outside this range.
So, my question is, what can I conclude about my simulations?

FileName            AcceptanceRate     AverageEnergy       Temperature(T)      Steps      Beads    BoltzmannConstant     Density(ρ)     Period        Epsilon(ε)    Sigma(σ)     
20241207_142120     0.7918             -505.07848          0.1                 1000000    216      1.000000              0.100000       12.926608     1.000000      1.000000       
20241207_143926     13.6485            -313.18169          0.5                 1000000    216      1.000000              0.100000       12.926608     1.000000      1.000000     
20241207_144654     35.0997            -36.5321            0.75                1000000    216      1.000000              0.100000       12.926608     1.000000      1.000000       
20241207_154529     35.325             -35.36303           0.75781             1000000    216      1.000000              0.100000       12.926608     1.000000      1.000000         
20241207_155925     37.887             -0.79558            0.76172             1000000    216      1.000000              0.100000       12.926608     1.000000      1.000000       
20241207_153359     38.1155            2.63461             0.76563             1000000    216      1.000000              0.100000       12.926608     1.000000      1.000000     
20241207_152539     39.3729            19.91722            0.78125             1000000    216      1.000000              0.100000       12.926608     1.000000      1.000000       
20241207_150407     43.9161            78.5104             0.8125              1000000    216      1.000000              0.100000       12.926608     1.000000      1.000000     
20241207_145439     52.2382            174.15694           0.875               1000000    216      1.000000              0.100000       12.926608     1.000000      1.000000     
20241207_142749     68.1442            369.13298           1.000000            1000000    216      1.000000              0.100000       12.926608     1.000000      1.000000       
20241207_164849     87.398900          522.571763          2.000000            1000000    216      1.000000              0.100000       12.926608     1.000000      1.000000  
20241207_165652     89.669600          533.149188          3.000000            1000000    216      1.000000              0.100000       12.926608     1.000000      1.000000  
20241207_170355     91.364000          546.224084          4.000000            1000000    216      1.000000              0.100000       12.926608     1.000000      1.000000  
20241207_171206     92.233400          554.666707          5.000000            1000000    216      1.000000              0.100000       12.926608     1.000000      1.000000  
20241207_172150     92.568000          557.861889          6.000000            1000000    216      1.000000              0.100000       12.926608     1.000000      1.000000  
20241207_174035     93.327300          566.236718          7.000000            1000000    216      1.000000              0.100000       12.926608     1.000000      1.000000  
20241207_174726     93.329800          570.317386          8.000000            1000000    216      1.000000              0.100000       12.926608     1.000000      1.000000  
20241207_175526     93.728900          575.362246          9.000000            1000000    216      1.000000              0.100000       12.926608     1.000000      1.000000  
20241207_141111     93.6728            579.78266           10.000000           1000000    216      1.000000              0.100000       12.926608     1.000000      1.000000  
20241207_180232     95.168400          669.359954          30.000000           1000000    216      1.000000              0.100000       12.926608     1.000000      1.000000  

Note: In the given table of data,

Everything is in reduced form.

Maximum displacement is the same for all temperatures.

The acceptance rate is represented as a percentage.

Maximum displacement is equal to 0.3.

Density is equal to 0.1.



How do you define the acceptance rate in the program? It should be the ration between the number of accepted moves / total moves. By definition, it cannot be larger than 1.

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90, It should be the ratio between the number of accepted moves and total moves —I just multiplied it by 100 to show it as a percentage.

What is the maximum displacement? And what is the density?

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90, maximum-displacement=0.3 and density=0.1.

What units are you using for the maximum displacement? And is it the same for all temperatures?

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90, In the given table of data in this post, everything is in reduced form. And, yes, the max. disp. is same for all temp..

As a general rule, the optimal maximum displacement is a thermodynamic state function. In particular, for an LJ system at reduced density $\rho^*=0.1$, the variation of the maximum displacement corresponding to a given acceptance ratio may require to be reduced by a factor of four going from $T^*=30$ to $T^*=0.5$.
Notice, however, that at $\rho^*=0.1$, one crosses the coexistence curve at temperatures around $1$ (the exact temperature may vary according to the presence of an interaction cutoff. A canonical simulation below the coexistence curve cannot produce clean results due to size effects.

the variation of the maximum displacement corresponding to a given acceptance ratio may require to be reduced by a factor of four --- Can you kindly attach reading material regarding this?

A canonical simulation below the coexistence curve cannot produce clean results due to size effects. --- So, what is your suggestion?

It depends on the problem one would like to solve and the required accuracy. For the gas-liquid phase transition Panagiotopoulos' Gibbs Ensemble technique may provide a good description of the coexistence curve ( but the neighborhood of the critical point requires special care). If a semi-quantitative answer is enough, other techniques are available. You may have a look at the Frenkel&Smit textbook Understanding Molecular Simulation.

Please ask new questions in new posts so that there's one question / request per post. The original question didn't ask for that reading material.
